# vtd-xml c++ compilation and installation error

Tags: c++, c, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

Has anybody used the c++ version of vtd-xml lib?

Recently I want to parse (need to traversal) xml files with c++ or c and got the idea that [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) is a perfect solution, but when compiling mingw output lots of warnings and errors.

I have looked through those errors and found some 'common sense error'. Do you have any idea if the c++ version of this vtd-xml lib is a reliable one? Or some alternatives libs which are suitable for xml parsing( fast and low memory consumption)? The version I downloaded is ver2.11

Comment: Show the code and the error/warnings messages you get. Also from the FAQ: "*When compiling the C version of VTD-XML, I see lots of warning messages. Is there anything wrong? To emulate Java's interface, the C version of VTD-XML use structs and functional pointers that cause those warning message. So it is ok, you can safely ignore those warning messages." This is inspiring confidence ;-)

Comment: If you search SO for "[c++] [xml]" or "[c++] [xml] library", you will find lots of posts about the subject.

Comment: c++ was compiled on linux and windows, haven't tested on Mingw? What is the error like? Can u work with the C version of it?

Comment: thanks for all your help. I have switched to linux and everything goes well.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of compilation error are you experiencing?

For the other question: we used the c++ library for our prototype (Windows with VS2012 and Linux) and it behaved very well.

Comment: So i assume you have problems compiling vtd with Linux, right,?

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that my colleague added that function, it was not in the original lib. He does not remember of any relevant problem during compilation process (both win and linux).